# Creating objects from states

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**I have two states:**

```
  const [firstState, setFirstState]   = useState(6.5)
  const [secondState, setSecondState] = useState(3.5)
```

**I wish to combine these two states into an object, like this:**

```
  const [myObject, setMyObject] = useState({
    first: {firstState},
    second: {secondState}
  });
//NOTE: This does not compile when i try to create state-object with state values.
```

I then send the object to a child-component as a prop which is later used for display.

`<ChildComponent objectToChild={myObject}/>`

What's the best pratice to combine states into an object?

Comment: Why? why you have to do that ? why you don't use two variable in one useState and pass this for `ChildComponent`

Comment: Maybe [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) might be more appropriate for you

Comment: You can create this as an object so it would be useState({ firstState: 6.5, secondState: 3.5 }); and later use this as an simply js object

Comment: Can i stil update the state though? @Freestyle09

Comment: @ArastoSahbaei Yes you can still update the state do it like  `setObject({...myObject, firstState: 20})` this will change only the firstState part of the object

Comment: As @harisu said, yes you can you only need to remember that you need to copy whole object from previous state and update only that key which you want to be updated, I will add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are different option

**1. Using the useState Hook**

```
const [myObject, setMyObject] = useState({
    first: firstState,
    second: secondState
  });
```

modify state

`setMyObject({...myObject, firstState })`

**2. Using the useReducer**

useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.

```
const initialState = {
    first: 'name',
    second: 'surname'
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action) {
    case 'first': return { ...state, first: state.first };;
    case 'second': return { ...state, second: state.second };;
    default: throw new Error('Unexpected action');
  }
};
```

use it like

`const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an object as an argument in useState method, so It would be like this:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
```

and call `setUser` method like this:

```
setUser(prevState => {
   return {...prevState, [user.firstState]: 6.5}
}
```

Read more about useState hook here:
https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate